# My custom combinator for handling RX exceptions is not working

Tags: c#, .net, exception, system.reactive

I have the following extensions method for IObservable ( Reactive Extensions ). I want to run an `Action` ( no return value ) but pass on the exception state of the run action using my `Maybe<T>` monad. If the action completes I wish to pass through None.Default otherwise Some containing the exception that was raised.

My implementation is below

```
public static IObservable<Maybe<Exception>> Catch<T>
    ( this IObservable<T> source
    , Action<T> action
    )
{
    var happy = source.Select(p => { 
        action(p); 
        return None<Exception>.Default; 
    });
    return happy.Catch<Maybe<Exception>,Exception>
        (e => Observable
                .Return(e.ToMaybe()).Concat(happy));

}
```

and I have a test case

```
[Fact]
public void TryShouldHandleExceptions()
{
               // Make a hot observable
    var b = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2 }.ToObservable().Publish().RefCount();

    // Execute actions and collect exception state
    IObservable<Maybe<Exception>> e = b.Catch(v => {
        if (v==1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Ouch");
        }
    });

    var r = e.ToEnumerable().ToList();

    r.Count().Should().Be(3);

    r[0].IsSome.Should().Be(false);
    r[1].IsSome.Should().Be(true);
    r[2].IsSome.Should().Be(false);

}
```

However the test case is failing and the exception bubbles
up instead of being handled by the RX Catch method. Note
sure what I have done wrong here. Any ideas?

BTW. Bonus point if you can come up with a better name
than `Catch` for this method.

Comment: Actually I just had a thought that the test is not quite doing what I think. Maybe when I resubscribe I'm resubscribing from the beginning rather from the next value. Though I thought making it ``hot`` like I did would fix that.

Comment: `Publish().RefCount()` does not really make it "hot".  It is still a cold observable when there are no observers.  Once an observer subscribes, it goes hot and additional observers will share the stream.  Once all observers unsubscribe, it goes cold again and will "start over" when the next observer subscribes.  This is because `RefCount()` is tracking the # of observers and switching it from cold <-> hot as the count changes.

Comment: Besides the problem of it starting over each time, it also has the problem that after the first exception and your `(e => Observable...` clause is triggered, the new replacement observable you return does not itself have a `Catch` clause attached, and so the _next_ exception will go uncaught (which, because you were starting over was your first exception repeated again).  You should have concated `happy.Catch(action)` instead of just `happy`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just being way too complicated. This works correctly

```
    public static IObservable<Maybe<Exception>> Catch<T>
        ( this IObservable<T> source
        , Action<T> action
        )
    {
        return source.Select(p => {
            try
            {
                action(p);
                return None<Exception>.Default; 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.ToMaybe();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: yeah that's the most straightforward way to do this and avoids all of the resubscribing logic.